# SMF.Net.WebClient - empty response from a web-site

Tags: xmlhttprequest, smartface.io

I've been using SMF.Net.WebClient successfully to access a web-site already. Now it has strange behavior when requesting a certain link:

```
  var wc = new SMF.Net.WebClient({
    URL : "http://www.invitro.ru/analizes/for-doctors/156/6671/?region_code=&section_id=156&element_id=6671",
    httpMethod : "GET",
    requestHeaders : ["Content-Type: text/html"],
    // When results are ready
    onSyndicationSuccess : function (e) {
        Pages.Webview.WV_Main.URL = this.responseText;
        Pages.Webview.show();            
    }, 
    timeoutInterval : 15        
  }); 
wc.run(true);
```

In this case,  onSyndicationSuccess responseText is always empty, although this.status = 200.

I even tried XmlHttpRequest with the same parameters and URL from Excel VBA. It worked fine!

What may be a problem here?

Comment: It seems a problem of getting the html response with WebClient.
Why you are using webCLient to show a HTML with WebView. WebClient generally uses to get JSON Restful services.
YOu can directly give the URL to WebView.

Comment: It is in a testing mode. I need to parse html-response in code to take some data from the page. Is there more appropriate approach to achieve my goal?

Comment: I suggest you to use runJS method for that kind of purposes http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/controls/webview/#hook-with-displayed-page

Answer (score 0):

A possible way around the problem - using SMF.UI.WebView object in a special way:

```
Pages.Webview.WV_Main.URL = ....
...
function Webview_WV_Main_OnLoad(e){
    var js = "document.body.innerHTML"

    Pages.Webview.WV_Main.runJS({javascript:js, callback:function(e){ 
        // e.result here is a string containing html-response
        }});  
}
```